# stop the widget from running in the background, on delete()

Tags: android, widget, kill

Hey,
Anyone knows how to kill widget on delete(). When i delete the widget its stays running in the background,it never dies unless i foreclose the whole app.
My app consists of 4 activities and the widget is not the main activity and im using thread instead of service for the appwidget.

All what i need is stop the widget from running in the background when i delete it.
i've tried using system.exit(0). It didn't work, all what it does is clear all the data in the widget.
Or if i can kill the app ondelete();

Any ideas? I'd really appreciated.

Comment: What kind of widget? We need more information.

Answer (score 2):

That is the normal behavior.  The process is kept around in case the app needs to run again.  This saves work, since it can probably just be re-used the next time the widget needs to update or the user launches the app.